# Android Navigation Component - OnNavigateUpListener

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, onbackpressed, navigationcontroller, up-navigation

I would like to attach a callback to when the Android Navigation Controller navigates up from a specific fragment (`findNavController().navigateUp()`). How can I achieve this functionality?

I've already heard about `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this)`. This only listens to the **system's back button** not the back arrow on the toolbar. I'd like to listen to the event where the user **presses the back arrow on the toolbar in the top-left corner**.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue. The OnBackPressedDispatcher only overrides the OS/System back button and not the Toolbar when using Android Navigation controller.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to find a solution. Here's what the onCreate() of my MainActivity looks like:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
my_toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

// The code below solved it for me. It overrides the toolbar back and then calls the OS back which is overridden in my fragment.
my_toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    onBackPressed()
}
```

And in my fragment, I do this in onActivityCreated()

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    // override custom back
}
```

Now I can override both toolbar back button and OS back button in a single handler.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` that contains the `NavHostFragment` you can add `onDestinationChanged` to the `NavController` listener

```
navController = findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.navHostFragment);
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this);

@Override
public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
    int destinationId = destination.getId();
    if (destinationId == R.id.YOUR_DESIRED_FRAGMENT_ID) // your own behavior...
}
```

you can then add any behavior you desire.

I hope this help.

Comment: How do I know what the previous destination is? I want it to happen only from a **specific fragment** to another **specific fragment**.

Comment: Then I believe you can add your desired behavior this specific fragment `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`.